# Is there a list about the supported ML-Algorithms in TensorFlow?

Tags: algorithm, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am writing my bachelor thesis on "Machine Learning in Java" and compare frameworks and libraries. Currently I am collecting information about the different machine learning algorithms supported by the framework. I write them down in Excel, and use this data to evaluate the individual frameworks. Now to my problem:

I can't find a list of supported ML algorithms in TensorFlow (Java-API). Is there a quick overview that I can use for this? I have already googled desperately, no success so far. Could someone please help me, that would be great.

Comment: TensorFlow's Java API provides only low-level APIs for defining Tensors, Ops and Graphs. They are not meant to be used as we do in Python. They are more useful when you're running a pre-trained model in Java.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I thought it would be possible to implement ML models in Python and then integrate them into Java applications.

Answer (score -1):

The list of tensorflow optimizers can be found here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers